# How to impose constraints based on previous solution in PuLP?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

So I have this mixed integer program where my indicator x is in 0 or 1
depending on if the item is used or not. I would like to maximise price of items in the bag according to the constraints in the below code.

*My question is*, I want to repeat this process repeatedly a finite number of times, and use the solution each time to impose further constraints for the next time/round.

The price fluctuates each time/round so different items will need to be packed. However, I am only allowing **one *free* change each time** I run the solver. For each additional change from the last solution set will come at a penalty of say -100 per each item. Toy example: So if the last solution was [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] and the new solution is [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] then a penalty would have incurred in the objective of -100 due to their being 2 changes from the last round. If it changed to [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0] then that would be unpenalised.

How do I impose this penalty in the objective and impose the 1 free change constraint?

The initial program is as follows:

```
items = [i for i in range(len(df))]
price = df['price'].to_dict()
volume = df['volume'].to_dict() 
weight = df['weight'].to_dict()


prob = LpProblem('mip',LpMaximize)
x = LpVariable.dicts("items", items, 0, 1, LpBinary)

#objective
prob += lpSum([(price[i]*x[i]) for i in items])

#constraints
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in items]) = 10
prob += lpSum([weight[i] * x[i] for i in items]) <= 1000
prob += lpSum([volume[i] * x[i] for i in items]) <= 5000

prob.solve()

#to get the solution in a list for reuse
current_solution = [x[i].varValue for i in items]
```

I thought about using dummy items in var[i] with prices = -100, but couldn't get it to work. Any help? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super easy.

I would try something like:

(1) Introduce a binary variable `d[i] ∈ {0,1}` and the constraints:

```
 -d[i] <= x[i] - x0[i] <= d[i]
```

where `x0` is the previous solution. (This has to implemented as two different constraints in PuLP. Also, we actually may relax `d` to be continuous between 0 and 1: it will be binary automatically.)

(2)  Add a variable `n` and the constraint:

```
  n = sum(i, d[i])
```

(3) Add a positive variable `n1 >= 0` and the constraint

```
  n1 >= n - 1
```

(4) Add a term to the objective

```
 -100*n1
```

(we want to minimize `100*n1` so I added the minus sign, as your obj is maximizing).

Comment: (1) Why do you need a coefficient of 2 or -2 for d[i]? x[i] - x0[i] could only be 1 - 1, or 0. (1-0) i.e. newly selected, (0-1) i.e. was removed, (0-0) i.e. not chosen again or (1-1) picked again.

(2) I'm not sure what the purpose of n is? What does the sum of i and d[i] give us anyway?

Thanks

Comment: How about (2)? Not really sure I follow the logic..

Comment: (2) n counts the number of differences.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to PuLP and this is all quite confusing.

So do you mean sum(i, d[i]) is basically lpSum([d[i] for i in items]) in PuLP?

And are n and n1 added by the following LpVariable.dicts("name", items, 0)
Or are they added as like constant variables essentially?

Comment: It is in pseudo code (math) notation. Translating into PuLP is trivial.